# Getting an out of memory exception with System.Threading.ReaderWriterCount

Tags: c#, asp.net, out-of-memory

I've got an asp.net application, it's running on DotNetNuke, under load we get the occasional out of memory exception.

I've got a dump loaded it into windbg.

the end of !dumpheap -stat is

```
1192a588    88684      2128416 AutoMapper.MappingEngine
79333594     9482      2266348 System.Byte[]
134b0034    88695      2838240 System.EventHandler`1[[AutoMapper.TypeMapCreatedEventArgs, AutoMapper]]
13d8703c    88684      4611568 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.CacheKey, AutoMapper],[System.Type, mscorlib]]
13d86dc8    88684      4611568 Castle.DynamicProxy.ModuleScope
13d865bc    88684      4611568 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[AutoMapper.Internal.TypePair, AutoMapper],[AutoMapper.IObjectMapper, AutoMapper]]
79327434    88703      4612556 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.Int32, mscorlib]]
6c38e4e4    88684      5675776 System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim
79330b24    87736      6458012 System.String
000d9c88      129     24186884      Free
793042f4   221202    101117016 System.Object[]
6c38e4a0 22703104    544874496 System.Threading.ReaderWriterCount
```

I can't find much information on the System.Threading.ReaderWriterCount, as it seems to be the problem.

What is the likely cause? Or failing that what's the best next step to work that out?

Based on the pointer from the given answer I had a look at ReaderWriterLockSlim. I wasn't using it directly, but I saw that it had 88684 instances, digging deeper I saw quite a few classes with that number of instances, pointing to AutoMapper.MappingEngine. This should be a singleton, so I've had a look at where it's being created. I suspect that it's the DI container and have made some changes around that to see if it helps

Comment: I had a couple of classes causing this problem. They were creating extra instances of the mapping engine, there were other classes being kept around when they shouldn't have been. I ended up decoupling a child class from a service (it had maintained a reference) and the service could then be garbage collected and the memory was freed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ReaderWriterLockSlim` is not a cheap class in memory footprint - that could be why your `ReaderWriterCount` instances are proliferating.  See [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/fe2ce8aa-dd78-42e6-b5f4-26df96a16bc2) for detailed info from Reflector.

Can you reduce usage of this class?  Maybe not all of them need to be Read/Write Locks, simple `Mutex`/`lock()` might work?

Note also that this class is `IDisposable` - perhaps you are not `Dispose()`-ing of them after you are through with them?

Comment: Thanks, though the weird thing is that I'm not using ReaderWriterLockSlim, at least not in any of my code. I do use linq to sql, and Oracle.DataAccess. Any Ideas as to what might be using it, or how I can find out?

Comment: @baralong - you need something like the .Net object tracking in Visual Studio 2010 (also earlier versions) : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264934.aspx